# Given a 2D image and projection height I have to project image as 3D image

Tags: three.js, projection

I have a circle and I have given height by which I have to project it. So, I have to create a cyliner by projecting circle. The View should be like 3D view.

Answer (score 1):

Use extrude geometry of three js.

Comment: Extrude geometry is creating weird wireframes by connecting diagonals. I don't want diagonal in my wireframe.